# an image as a button

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I want an image that I added into a canvas to work as a button.
When I clicked the image, an alert must shown. Also clicking the rest of the canvas must be forbidden. How can I do this? 
Thanks.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var quizbg = new Image();
    quizbg.src = "basla.png";
    context.drawImage(quizbg,0,0);
}

<script>

<body>
<div id="ccontainer">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var quizbg = new Image();
        quizbg.src = "basla.png";
        quizbg.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(quizbg,0,0);
        }
        canvas.onclick= function() { 
            alert('Bike');
            canvas.onclick = false;
        }  
    }
    </script>



    <body>
    <div id="ccontainer">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Working example, http://jsfiddle.net/wcxc2/

Comment: This worked. I have a question too. This code must be work only once. Then the image and its event will be hidden. How can I provide this feature?

Comment: if I have two different images how can I do ? I tried the code, but the alert of second image is only shown.

Comment: You need to have coordinates of each image saved and accessible!

Comment: Post another question for this!

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me the way? Should I work on this code or research new functions ?

Comment: Ok. I am posting a new question.

Comment: POST another question and i will answer it there!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [kineticjs](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/) tutorial (what you want is made easier)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write all the logic by yourself.

1) use

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.pageX, e.pageY;
});
```

to bind mouse

2) check if the click is within the rectangle of a button

```
if(inRect(e.pageX, e.pageY, buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)) {
  alert("the button has been clicked");
}
```

Of course you have to write inRect function :)

The other thing is that if your canvas is not at [0, 0] you will have to substract its offset from the event's position.

Here is the logic with use of canvasquery http://cssdeck.com/labs/svleh8dq

Comment: Can I use two different click function in the same script?

Comment: Sure - the .addEventListener can bind as many different functions as you want